# Eliminar una migración por completo (junto con su clase) en Laravel. Eliminar tabla

Tags: laravel, datatables, eloquent, tablas, migration

Tengo un problema al crear nuevamente las tablas, me dice que la clase ya existe.

Mi problema desde el principio fue que cree las tablas en desorden, así como esta la lista.

- Tabla Idiomas
- Tabla Experiencias
- Tabla Usuarios

Cuando las tenia que haber creado en este orden.

- Tabla Usuarios
- Tabla Idiomas
- Tabla Experiencias

Esto porque las tablas de abajo (Idiomas y Experiencias) tienen llave foránea que depende de la tabla Usuarios.

Entonces decidí crearlas de nuevo, las elimine "manualmente" solo borre los archivos, y al intentar volver a ejecutar el comando

> php artisan make:migration create_usuario_table

Me sale el error de que la clase ya existe.

```
InvalidArgumentException  : A CreateUsuariosTable class already exists.

protected function ensureMigrationDoesntAlreadyExist($name)
  {
    if (class_exists($className = $this->getClassName($name))) {
    throw new InvalidArgumentException("A {$className} class already exists.");
    }
  }
```

estuve buscando en el foro y encontre que se puede usar

> Schema::dropIfExists('usuarios');
>
> Schema::drop('idiomas');

pero no me funciona, o lo estoy aplicando mal.

**Espero me puedan ayudar con esto, gracias.**

Comment: quiza aun estas iniciando tu proyecto y no tengas datos de relevancia, entonces lo mas facil de hacer es eliminar la base de datos(de forma manual: drop table mydatabase) y posterior crear nuevamente tu base de datos y recien ejecutar " php artisan migrate".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La instrucción `Schema::drop('idiomas');` *o similar*, se incluye en las migraciones para hacer rollbacks, lo que no siempre funciona, por ejemplo si hay algún problema añadiendo claves ajenas. Puede ser necesario ir a la tabla de migraciones y eliminar el registro correspondiente a la tabla donde falla la migración, antes de corregir el código.

***Vamos a suponer que estas trabajando solo y no tienes datos que necesites preservar en la base de datos.***

Antes de ejecutar las migraciones, partimos de una **base de datos vacía**, sin ninguna tabla, lo que incluye la tabla *migrations*. Puedes eliminar todas las tablas o la base de datos, volviendo a crearla.

Deberías tener un fichero de migración por cada tabla que vas a crear en la BD. Revisa que no crees más de una tabla en algún fichero.

Si creas las claves ajenas al crear las tablas, estos ficheros deberán tener un orden determinado. Tienes la posibilidad de renombrar los ficheros si el orden no es el correcto. O dejar la creación de claves ajenas para una última migración.

El proceso será ejecutar, limpiar la BD y volver a ejecutar... hasta que todas las migraciones se ejecuten correctamente.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta me ayudo en algunas cosas, el problema que tuve fue que Laravel por algún motivo se "crasheo", lo que hice fue borrar todas las tablas (respaldándolas) hacer un cache:clean cerrar y volver a abrir VisualStudio Code y crear otra migración con un nombre distinto, lo cual salio todo normal, cuando intente volver a hacer la migración que me daba problemas "create_usuario_table" para mi sorpresa no me dio el error. Algo muy curioso pero que muchas veces no llega a pasar. GRACIAS POR SUS RESPUESTAS.

Answer (score 1):

A mi me ha sucedido lo mismo y como me pasaba en varias tablas y no tenía ganas de borrarlas todas, y no tenía datos en ellas (no me importaba eliminar algunas migraciones) he hecho lo siguiente:

1. He cambiado la fecha del sistema a la que me convenía (una fecha y hora anteriores a las de la creación de las migraciones que me daban problemas (las que tenían claves foráneas de tablas que había creado después).
2. Para no perderlo, he copiado en un archivo (cualquiera) el código de cada una de las migraciones  que tenía que borrar para volverlas a crear (porque he probado a renombrarlas pero no ha funcionado => el sistema me decía ya existía una tabla con dicho nombre).
3. He borrado (del listado lateral) cada una de las migraciones que tenía que cambiar de fecha (para ponerlas en su orden lógico).
4. He vuelto a crear cada una de las migraciones con la fecha del sistema que me convenía del "pasado" y se me han ordenado correctamente y ya no me han generado problemas las claves foráneas al ejecutar "refresh" para generar todas las migraciones nuevamente.